# How to use $ regex value as a php variable?

Tags: php, regex

### The case

i have already declared a php variable like this

```
    <?php $covid19=200;?>
```

Then i have html a markup like this

```
    {{:covid19:}}
```

I have a regex to match this patern like this

```
    /\{\{:(.*?):\}\}/si
```

i have a preg replace rule

```
    <p>$1</p>
```

and it works perfectly and produce this result

```
   <p>covid19</p>
```

Everything is fine

### My expectation

i want this result to be produced

```
    <?php echo $covid19;?>
```

ofcourse it is

```
    200
```

Comment: Is your expected output `<?php echo $covid19;?>` or `200`?

Comment: What **exactly** have you tried? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use external variables this way. $1 refers to a variable *within* the regexp, not the external one. It's just a value of the first matched brackets in the regexp.

To use external variable, as well as any other expression, you need to use preg_replace_callback() function.

Something like this (I didn't run this code, may contain errors):

```
preg_replace_callback('/\{\{:(.*?):\}\}/si', function ($matches) { return $GLOBALS[$matches[1]]; }, $subject);
```

Note, I use $GLOBALS array, assuming your variables are global. If they aren't you'll need to use some other way to reach the variable in the correct scope.

Answer (score 3):

Just use this as the replacement:

```
<?php echo \$$1; ?>
```

You just add the literal text and escape the `$` for the variable.  This will result in `200` so long as that code is then parsed by PHP.

If not, and you need to replace with `200` (the value of `$covid19`).  Then so long as `$covid19` is in global scope, you could use:

```
$result = preg_replace_callback('/\{\{:(.*?):\}\}/si',
                                function($m) {
                                    return $GLOBALS[$m[1]];
                                },
                                $string);
```

Comment: Had just made a demo of this very code https://3v4l.org/q0lVO but got distracted by a comment on another answer. You may as well add it to yours...